# Equation for the area of a rounded ends rectangle

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am really struggling with this question on my assignment and need some guidance.
The question reads: To build the semi-circular ends costs $10/m$, and to build the the straight sides will cost $2/m$. $\$360$ is available to build it to it's largest area.
a) show that the area of the shape can be given by $A=9r(20-πr)$, where **r** is the radius of each semi-circular end.
[image]

Comment: What is your try??

Comment: This is what I Tried: A=2(h(2r))+10(πr^2 ) . 360=4rh+10πr^2 is this right? what is the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the radius of the ends be $r$ and the length of the sides be $h$.  What is the area in terms of $r,h$?  What is the cost of the shape in terms of $r,h$?  Set that to $360$ and you can solve for one variable in terms of the other.  Plug that into your area formula, differentiate, set to zero ....

Comment: This is what I Tried: A=2(h(2r))+10(πr^2 )                                                                                            .                           360=4rh+10πr^2    is this right?  what is the next step?

Comment: No, neither is right.  The $2$ and $10$  only apply to costs, so are not part of the area.  The $360$ is linear, but your formula is quadratic in length.

Comment: My bad so **A=2rh+πr^2** and the I need to solve for **h** so **-2rh=πr^2** , **h=πr^2/-2r**?

Comment: You solve the cost equation for $h$, then plug that into $A$.

Comment: Could you please show me by what you mean with cost equation? and how you got it?

Comment: You have $2\pi r$ of circular fence and $2h$ of straight fence, so $360=10\cdot 2\pi r+2\cdot 2h$

Comment: Thank you this is all I needed I was trying to find the area by using the area equation and when I needed to use the perimeter.